# How to get and display images from a certain gallery Albums?

Tags: php

I am creating a personal website. I was able to add images and create gallery albums on the admin page of my website meanwhile on my web visitor's page, the gallery albums are showing however I want the images that I uploaded on a specific album in the admin page to appear in the front-end when a visitor clicks on a certain gallery album. How can I make this possible using php?

I've tried this code but it didn't work.

```
<?php
$result = array();
$dir = 'photo-album/';
foreach(glob($dir. '*.jpg') as $filename){

    $result[] = "<div class=\box\"><img src=\$filename\"></div>";
}  
  ?>
```

By the way, those gallery albums and photos that I've created and added on the back-end doesn't have a database rather it is directly save on my localhost directory folder that I've created which contains all the gallery albums that I have on the admin page.

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is that you're looking in the wrong directory. Are you sure it is in `YOURDOMAIN/photo-album` ? Isn't it in a sub directory? Furthermore, how are those albums separated from one and another?

Comment: What doesn't work in your code? Do you receive an error, or warning? Are the photos saved under photo-album/ ?

Comment: Only adding to an array will not display them. Also make sure you use the correct quotes in `"<div class=\box\"><img src=\$filename\"></div>"` (`\b` and `\$` are missing a quote). And make sure `$filename` also contains `$dir`

Comment: @Kevin those albums are separated by its name, for example: Family, friends etc. And you are correct photo-album is the main directory and there are sub-directories under it. Basically, it will depend on how many albums I've created in the back-end.
What I want is, when the user click on the album it will show the images saved on that album.

Comment: So create links that pass the sub-directory name to your script as a URL parameter then, and then use that value to read only the images from the corresponding folder. (Of course you should secure this a bit more, i.e. either make sure the passed folder name is on a list of allowed ones, or if you want this to be dynamic so that it will automatically work for new folders you add later, take measures to make sure the passed value can not be used for a _path traversal attack_.)